# Where are akka.actor.ActorRef ask / tell shortcuts ? ! defined in API?

Tags: scala, akka

Where can I find the API for ActorRef.? and ActorRef.! in http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current? There are multiple versions of each, but I can't find them anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!` is in [`akka.actor.ActorRef`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/ActorRef.html#!(message:Any)(implicitsender:akka.actor.ActorRef):Unit)

`?` is in [`akka.pattern.AskSupport`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/pattern/AskSupport.html#ask(actorSelection:akka.actor.ActorSelection):akka.pattern.AskableActorSelection)

Comment: As you can see, the Scala API is provided by an implicit conversion. All to keep the Java API clean from the Scala API's symbolic method names: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorRef.scala#L157

Comment: In latest API docs the members added by implicit conversion are displayed: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/snapshot/#akka.actor.ActorRef